# Entity - Does two entities retrieved from the session have same values

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I was asked in an interview that say you have a hibernate session active and you retrieve an entity from it - Customer entity. You make some changes to the entity but do not save that to the database by calling em.flush or em.persist. Now you retrieve the same entity from the database again. Will it have the changes you have done earlier?

Comment: pls remove the tag entity-framework. I think it will retrieve the entity from the db, without the changes

Comment: Well, what happened when you tried this? That would be the first step of research to take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When retrieving the entity second time, you get exactly the same entity as the first time (i.e., `e2 == e1`). As it's the same object, it'll have all the changes.

Comment: I hope, I'm talking no nonsense, but that's how I understand the 1st level cache. Having two objects representing the same entity would easily lead to too many problems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It will have all the changes .

That 's why it has a method [refresh()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#refresh-java.lang.Object-) on `EntityManger` in case you want to overwrite the changes from DB values.